# My react component is rendering 1 too many child components

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and struggling with working on why this is happening

I have a component, which takes an array, maps it and then for each element it renders a new component

```
class CallingPattern extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { serviceId } = this.props.match.params

    this.state = {
      serviceId: serviceId,
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>CallingPattern page</h1>
        <h4>Current Journey ServiceID: {this.state.serviceId}</h4>
        <CallingStation serviceId={this.state.serviceId}/>
        <div className="calling-stations">
          // journeyData is a local JSON file 
          {journeyData.service.stops.map((stop, i) => {
            {console.log("mapping")} // logs 8 times (length of array) 
            return (
              <CallingStation
                key={`station-${i}`}
                stopInfo={stop}
                serviceId={this.state.serviceId}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CallingPattern;
```

I'm expecting 8 CallingStations to be rendered (one for each in the array, which has a .length of 8). Here's CallingStation code:

```
class CallingStation extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(`Rendered!`)
    return (
      <div>
         <div>
           Calling Station stop: { this.props.stopInfo ? this.props.stopInfo.location.crs : "" }
         </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CallingStation;
```

On the page, there are 9 CallingStations (the first one doesn't have a 'this.props.stopInfo' but DOES have 'this.props.serviceId'.

Can anyone help me understand or point me in the direction of resources that are related?

Comment: Could you also share the content of your json data please?

Comment: Based on your JSON data, you should have 17 stops, do you see 18?

Comment: Ah yes sorry this is the JSON data for the second train, which is 17 stops but I see 18 rendered, with the first one on the page having no this.props.stopInfo (but does have this.props.serviceId)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here. There is an extra `CallingStation` in your `render` method :)

```
<h4>Current Journey ServiceID: {this.state.serviceId}</h4>
<CallingStation serviceId={this.state.serviceId}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `JSON` data the `journeyData.service.stops.length` will be 17. You can log it to the console using `console.log(journeyData.service.stops.length)` in your render method and remove this line `<CallingStation serviceId={this.state.serviceId}/>` it doesn't make sense before mapping. To work with large JSON data you better use a good json viewer i suggest this chrome extension it's fantastic [JSON viewer Awesome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-viewer-awesome/iemadiahhbebdklepanmkjenfdebfpfe).

```
render() {
  console.log(journeyData.service.stops.length)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>CallingPattern page</h1>
      <h4>Current Journey ServiceID: {this.state.serviceId}</h4>
      <div className="calling-stations">
        // journeyData is a local JSON file 
        {journeyData.service.stops.map((stop, i) => {
          {console.log("mapping")} // logs 8 times (length of array) 
          return (
            <CallingStation
              key={`station-${i}`}
              stopInfo={stop}
              serviceId={this.state.serviceId}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```